# Windows bat file - deletion from directory

Tags: file, batch-file, delete-file

Could you please help me with following problem?
Very often I must do the same task which is deleting almost all files from one directory - all files but 2 of them (let say 1st.file and 2nd.file).
I found multiple solutions how to erase all from directory but have no idea how to work this one out. 
Could you point to where to find solution?

Comment: I do not completly understand your problem. Could you give some details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `DONOTDELETE.ME` with your file and that file won't be deleted.

```
@echo off
for /r . %%a in (*.*) do (
    IF NOT "%%~nxa" == "DONOTDELETE.ME"  (
         DEL "%%a"    )
)
```

You could also just do `attrib -r` to the files in question and remove the read-only flag afterwards like so:

```
@echo off
cd \myFiles
attrib myFiles\DONOTDELETE1.ME +r
attrib myFiles\DONOTDELETE2.ME +r
del myFiles\*.* /q /s /a-r
attrib myFiles\DONOTDELETE1.ME -r
attrib myFiles\DONOTDELETE2.ME -r
for /f %%a in ('dir myFiles/ad /b') do echo rd myFiles\%%a /q/s
```

Comment: Consdider marking your answer with the checkmark on the left site of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might get you started.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET RemoveFolder=C:\Temp

MV %RemoveFolder%\1st.file 1st.file
MV %RemoveFolder%\2nd.file 2nd.file
RD /S /Q %RemoveFolder%
IF NOT EXIST %RemoveFolder% MD %RemoveFolder%
MV 1st.File %RemoveFolder%
MV 2nd.File %RemoveFolder%

SET RemoveFolder=
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hackish, but you could just change the attributes of the files you do not want to delete...then exclude all files that have that attribute when you call erase.

Calling the follwing like this:
TestDelete.Bat "c:\DeleteAllFilesExcept", LeaveFile1.txt, LeaveFile2.txt

```
ATTRIB +H %2
ATTRIB +H %3

erase %1 /A-H

ATTRIB -H %2
ATTRIB -H %3
```

Of course, this will not work if you are intending to delete hidden files from the directory.